# How I can add some items to the code completion combobox of the Delphi IDE

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, ota

I'm working in a Delphi IDE expert and I wonder if it's possible add new items to the code completion combobox displayed by the Delphi IDE when the user press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>

UPDATE:
What I need is add items to the code completion list based in a specified type.

example suppose which I have a type called `TMytype`, what I want to do is add addional items to the code completion list when the user type a variable of the type  `TMytype`

check this image

[image]

Comment: The IDE shows what it can find. Include the unit containing defines what you're missing in the uses clause then ctrl+space will show them too..

Comment: Thanks @Sertac, but I need add some addiional items not present in a unit file. in this case I need to read the items from a XML file because the IDE extention work with Custom Live template.

Comment: implement IOTACodeInsightManager, IOTACodeInsightSymbolList

Comment: Tell your Delphi version please !

Comment: Agree with Sertac, list of the code completion items is built dynamically from the (public) methods, properties and variables from the current scope (method, class or uses scope). In fact I don't get what you're trying to do. What do you mean with the _My Item 1..N_ ?  Could you describe how do these items should behave, please ? Note that the list is built automatically from the items from a current scope so if you put there "some items" then they will suggest you nonsense (compiler will reject you with it). The answers here are talking about code templates. Isn't that what you need ?

Comment: @TLama the items which i want to load are present in a XML file. my final goal is just extended the code completion list with custom values, the `My Item 1`  can be a prefiled method with the params values, something like method('Foo',1,nil).

Comment: Ah, I see. So you are looking for a code templates. These templates are included in the code completion list too, but there are also some filtering rules. Unfortunately I don't know more about it (but I guess it will be also based on a scope). I would personally follow the article from the answer posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8451012/960757) by [menajraz](http://stackoverflow.com/users/744588/menjaraz). Interesting question anyway.

Comment: @TLama I know about code(live) templates, but is not what I'm looking.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you more, it's not clear for me what you're asking here. You've said few comments before _the My Item 1 can be a prefiled method with the params values, something like method('Foo',1,nil)_ but that perfectly fits to the code templates. Even more, with _live_ code templates, you can predefine method values and when you'll use this template, you'll just jump with the TAB key through those parameter values to modify them. But this can be optional, you can define the  template just with the "fixed" values, without this TAB jumping.

Comment: Do you know of other IDE implementing similar features ?

Comment: This is my guess work trying to restate the requirement : Need for a *context sensitive code insight manager* implementing the logic of a dynamic and automatic insertion of some member/method along with their respective implementation (placeholder) to a class type definition given some parametric knowledge stored in an external file (the class domain, member/method signature). I'm I right?

Comment: @menjaraz, for what you're describing would be the best `Code Input Helper` from CnPack. It works as the code completion list (pops when you're typing) and it displays the same list as code completion do but you can even define there your own symbols including their scope. What is the best, it's [open source](http://code.google.com/p/cnpack/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fcnwizards%2FSource) so if you want the inspiration take it from there.

Comment: @menjaraz, yes this is a valid description which I want.

Comment: @TLama I will check the `Code Input Helper` feature which you mention. thank for the interest on my question :)

Comment: @Salvador: Until you edit the question (elaborate please), every attempt to answer it would be pure speculation. Why don't you for example disclose the xml file you've knocked out using template ? I'm strongly convinced that my effort to restate your requirement is not complete even if you say that it's valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your question somewhat confusing but if you are in search of credible source on "Custom Live Templates" and the like on Delphi, head to the blog of Cary Jensen [here](http://caryjensen.blogspot.com/2011/04/live-templates-revisited.html).

**Edit**:

Looking forward to further improvement of the scope of the question, I suggest here another direction to explore:

- Source code manipulation using IOTAEditor, IOTASourceEditor, IOTAEditReader and the like
- Some Parsing for sanity check prior to apply any modification.
- Adoption of Client DataSet as a format to store data (It's serializable) to simplify the coding of IDE editors.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I haven't fully grasped the extent of what you are asking here, but you can add templates simply by going to 'View|Templates' from the Delphi IDE.  This then opens a template viewer.  Press the '+' icon.  It opens a template1.xml document which you can then edit so create your new item.

If you wish to do this programatically, just add an xml file (of the same format) to the ..\RAD Studio\code_templates folder.